# onDraw Custom View inside a Scrollview

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, ondraw

I have a custom view (width = 2000) inside a Horizontal Scrollview (width = 480). So there's a region that is scrollable.

When `onDraw()` is called, the dirty rectangle (returned by `getClipBounds()`) returns the whole view's dimensions, so I draw the whole view including the area that is not visible. As a consequence, when I scroll, `onDraw()` is not called any more, because the areas that become visible were already drawn and somehow remembered.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.getClipBounds(r); // returns 2000 x 400
}
```

This works fine!!!
However my custom view can be as wide as 20,000 or more, and things start to get slow. My concern is that the cached drawing uses a lot of memory. I don't think the drawing is being saved as bitmap because it would already have crashed, so how are these draw commands (lines and text, mostly) being saved?
Is there a way to specify that `onDraw()` should only request the visible portion of the view, and when scrolling it keeps calling `onDraw()`? Or is there any other approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Android uses [hardware accelerated "display lists"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#hardware-model) for drawing since Android 3.0. This causes the display list for the whole view to be cached.

If the view within the ScrollView is really big you can [disable hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling) for the view.

We do this by subclassing ScrollView and overriding the `onAttachedToWindow()` method with this:

```java
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow()
{
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Comment: You have really save my day! I view this answer at "http://www.codeitive.com/0yxVVjeeeV/ondraw-custom-view-inside-a-scrollview.html" and it solves my problem where my text view inside a scrollview always produces some hiccups during scrolling. I search the net to find this answer here to give you a vote. Thanks.